# Is it possible to post to your own timeline on Facebook using GraphAPI (not a page or a group, your own user timeline)

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-graph-api

I've been trying to build an app in Python to post to my own user timeline rather than a page or a group, it seems like that functionality once existed but may have been deprecated (according to one post I read that suggested it was removed in November last year). I've been trawling Google for an answer to this but it seems hard to nail down. Is this possible to do and if so, what app permissions do I need and what type of token should I be getting (user/app)?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: No, that is not possible any more. It was removed a long time ago already, when API version 2.4 was introduced, IIRC.

Comment: Thank you very much.